# Enabling/disabling network sharing by non-admin users Windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, file-sharing

Non-admin user need to enable/disable network sharing of folder. How to give this rights to him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use NTFS permissions to control access to the folders in the share instead of sharing/unsharing a folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Power Users and Administrators are the only ones that can create network shares.